# Is there a word for someone born through incest?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word 'bastard' is used liberally throughout Game of Thrones and it made me wonder about the children born through incest.

Comment: a human being for starters.  If born out of wedlock, a bastard.

Comment: "A product of incest" may sound cold, and while preferring Kristina Lopez' "human being," I guess "product" is a step above "inbred hick," as horatio provides in his answer.

Comment: An illegitimate child for a baby born out of wedlock, used to be a common term until the 70s, but that's a rough guess of mine.

Comment: @rhetorician Rhetoric! See TFD "2. A direct result; a consequence: "*Is history the product of impersonal social and economic forces?" (Anthony Lewis)*." -- history is not factory-made to be sold in the market, you see.

Comment: @rhetorician "2a thing or **person** that is the result of an action or process: *her perpetual suntan was the product of a solarium* a **person** whose character and identity have been formed by a particular period or situation: *an ageing academic who is a product of the 1960s* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/product

Comment: @Kris: No argument with definition number two. I'd be comfortable using the word in that sense in this sentence, for example: "Macro-evolutionists look at the human species as merely a product of slime and time." When referring to a human being, however, I think the connotations of the word "product" require the use of a different word. Call it a personal preference of mine. If I can win a few people to my way of thinking in this regard, then yeah, I guess the art of persuasion is at work, doing its thing. Are YOU persuaded? Don

Comment: Kristina Lopez, calling them "a human being" is literally correct but non-specific enough to be useless.  It's also morally laudable, but it reminds me of a very similar word that fell victim to the euphemism treadmill: cretin.  It originally meant "Christian", and was intended to lend dignity to the intellectually handicapped, by reminding others that they were "still Christian".  But it became pejorative over time.

Answer (score 17):

"Inbred" is pretty close, though not strictly confined to incest, though in common usage it is meant as an insult and the incestuous implication is the primary intention (e.g. "inbred hick")

"Inbreeding" is the interbreeding of closely related individuals.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there's a specific word - [incestuous love-child](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22incestuous+love+child%22&oq=%22incestuous+love+child%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.981j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is probably the closest you'll get.